# CRM Owner Of Entity Not Records

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

Suppose we are working in online CRM by multiple developers.

Suddenly I got to know that someone has created the Entity which I was going to create.

My question is, at this point may I know that who has created this Entity(not records) in the CRM.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Auditing will help, but oddly does not audit entity creation. It would pick up things like changes to security roles, which the person may have done to ensure their new entity is available to users, but this is a clue, not a definitive answer.

Comment: Did any of the answers help you out?

Answer (score 3):

You can't know which user made the customization (created an entity, added an attribute, ...)

`MetadataSchema` tables don't log the users performing customization

Answer (score 3):

We track a full history of changes to Entities by working on separate development organizations, and checking in our changes in Source Control afterwards.

You can use the [Solution Packager for Microsoft Dynamics 2011](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/crmmusings/archive/2012/05/31/solution-packager-enable-source-control-for-solutions-in-crm-2011.aspx#.Ub7yHUA3DwQ) to help you do this.

A typical **development** flow would be

- Developers develop against their own personal development organization (Online/On-premise), in a solution with the same publisher / name
- They export the developer solution
- They unpack the zip file into the XML structure
- And check it into source control, merging it with the master version

A typical **deployment into the integration organization** would be

- Get a latest version of the XML structure from source control
- Package it into a .zip solution
- Import it into the integration organization

This way, you have a full history of all changes, linked to the developers, and you can make controlled merges, using merging tools you're familiar with.

**Reference:** Microsoft released a very thorough whitepaper on Lifecycle management. Read about it [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/crm/archive/2013/05/17/release-alm-for-microsoft-dynamics-crm-2011-crm-solution-lifecycle-management.aspx).

Comment: Working offline and importing changes (and using different publishers for each dev) will help, although this is harder with the feature differences between on-premises and Online at the moment

Comment: Do you mean on-premise = offline and online = hosted solution? The key here is import/export solution. Although I haven't worked with the hosted crm solution (online) I would guess this supported in both versions. No?

Comment: The only thing you'd need is the possibility to export/import, which you can do in any of the deployment types. I've expanded my answer a bit with possible flows for development/deployment.

Comment: Added a link to the microsoft whitepaper on this subject.

Answer (score 2):

Honestly the easiest way is just to add it in the entity description, with an email & date/time.

Anything else is overkill in my opinion and suggests their is an issue with managing resources.